# Angular component testing: Asynchronous test fails without sleep #47006

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a component that allows images uploading, once the user adds an image, it emits an event (the parent should handle it), but doing some unit test over that component I'm not able to pass the test without doing some sleep (wait for event to be triggered).

Test purpose: Validate (spy) the event is emitted

```js
spyOn(component.fileAdded, 'emit');
uploadFiles(element, [new File([''], 'test_file.png')]);
fixture.detectChanges();

expect(component.fileAdded.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  filePath: jasmine.any(String),
  fileBase64: jasmine.any(String),
});
```

[See reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-async-code-testing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I tested:

- With waitForAsync + async fn -> FAIL
- With waitForAsync + await whenStabale fn -> FAIL
- With fakeAsync + tick -> FAIL
- With fakeAsync + flush -> FAIL
- With fakeAsync + flushMicrotasks -> FAIL
- With fakeAsync + whenStable -> FAIL
- Native async with sleep -> PASS

I'm missing something or doing something wrong?

**Reproduction of the bug**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-async-code-testing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is one of those rare occasions where `waitForAsync, await, tick, flush, whenStable` does not have control over the promise in the queue and mainly it does not have control over `reader.onload` but a `setTimeout` used by `sleep` works because the `reader.onload` finishes in that time.

What I usually do in a situation like this is to put the promise that I don't have control over in a private method and just mock it. In this case, you have already done that. Any of the above methods should work with this methodology.

```
fit(
    'with async + await',
    async () => {
      spyOn(component.fileAdded, 'emit');
      
      // !! This is the most important line.
      // !! We are spying on fileToBase64 private method and resolving it to
      // and array. You can resolve it to whatever you wish.
      spyOn(component as any, 'fileToBase64').and.resolveTo([]);
      uploadFiles(element, [new File([''], 'test_file.png')]);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      await fixture.whenStable();

      expect(component.fileAdded.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        filePath: jasmine.any(String),
        fileBase64: jasmine.any(String),
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me :).

I ended moving that logic into a collaborator (like your answer) then inside test I override via providers in tests. Something like:

 provide: BrowserBase64Converter,
 useClass: FakeBrowserBase64Converter

Thank you! :)